# Making your mouse scroll with visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I couldn't find anything about this so i'm asking it here. I know how to move my mouse and send clicks etc. but I would like to know if it's possible to make your mouse scroll up or down using visual basic. Would also be great to choose the scroll distance. (Just to clarify I don't want to do anything in the form, I want to also scroll outside of the form)

I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: A mouse doesn't scroll. A window scrolls. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: I mean that i'm trying to simulate scrolling with your scroll wheel on your mouse

Comment: Searching your last comment gives me MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, how you tried that?

Comment: What does "simulate scrolling" mean?  You roll the wheel, the mouse sends a scroll message, an app responds.  No need to simulate anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [flag MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL of the mouse event function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx) is what you are looking for.

From [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2211deb6-ee9d-49fb-a037-b590f9415c20/simulating-scroll-button-and-wheel?forum=vbgeneral), I got a sample that could help (I haven't tested it).

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents Tmr As New Timer With {.Interval = 2000}

    Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL As Integer = &H800 'The amount of movement is specified in mouseData.
    Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_HWHEEL As Integer = &H1000 'Not available for 2000 or XP

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="mouse_event")> _
    Private Shared Sub mouse_event(ByVal dwFlags As UInteger, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal dwData As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As UInteger)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.KeyPreview = True
        Tmr.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Tmr_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Tmr.Tick
        MouseScroll(False, 10) 'scrolls Down 10 wheel clicks
        'MouseScroll(True, 1) 'scrolls Up 1 wheel click
    End Sub

    Private Sub MouseScroll(ByVal up As Boolean, ByVal clicks As Integer)
        If up Then
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, (clicks * 120), 0)
        Else
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, -(clicks * 120), 0)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I found the same post and was able to fix it myself, thanks for taking time out of your day to help me.